# ffmpeg to detect silence in the right channel only

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I need to detect the silence in the right channel of a video file. The left channel is program audio, the right channel is LTC. I need to use the start time of the LTC as a slate to "nudge" the video to align w/ a master audio track during editing.

The following two pass procedure works but is inefficient as I am calling ffmpeg twice:

```
"C:\Program Files\ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe" -i "C:\Video\inputfile.ts" -af "pan=mono|FC=FR" %temp%\temp.wav

"C:\Program Files\ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe" -i "%temp%\temp.wav" -af silencedetect=noise=-18dB:d=0.5  %temp%\tempx.wav
```

I need to learn how to chain the two audio filters together so this can be accomplished in a single pass.

I tried using the technique described in this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1183205/applying-specific-channel-to-ffmpeg-filter) but I am having syntax issues. I actually extracted the audio from the video and tried the referenced example and this is what I get:

```
C:\Program Files\ffmpeg>ffmpeg -i %temp%\test.wav -af "pan=1c|c0=c0,silencedetect=noise=-18dB:d=.5" %temp%\temp.wav

ffmpeg version 2.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers built on May 22 2014 19:56:44 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3  --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --ena
ble-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --e
nable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libi
lbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-
libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enabl
e-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable
-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --
enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-l
ibx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-decklink --en
able-zlib
  libavutil      52. 66.100 / 52. 66.100
  libavcodec     55. 52.102 / 55. 52.102
  libavformat    55. 33.100 / 55. 33.100
  libavdevice    55. 10.100 / 55. 10.100
  libavfilter     4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswscale      2.  5.102 /  2.  5.102
  libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, wav, from 'C:\Users\brad\AppData\Local\Temp\test.wav':
  Duration: 00:19:45.62, bitrate: 1536 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16
, 1536 kb/s
[auto-inserted resampler 0 @ 006ebf40] Cannot select channel layout for the link
 between filters auto-inserted resampler 0 and Parsed_silencedetect_1.
[auto-inserted resampler 0 @ 006ebf40] Unknown channel layouts not supported, tr
y specifying a channel layout using 'aformat=channel_layouts=something'.
Error opening filters!
Conversion failed!
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `ffmpeg` is too old. [Download](https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/) a new one.

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -af "pan=1c|c0=c1,silencedetect=noise=-18dB:d=0.5" -f null -
```

- No need to output a file if you just need the silence info. You can use the null muxer to output nothing.
- Left channel is `c0=c0`, right channel is `c0=c1`. See [pan filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pan).
- `d=.5` will give you an error: `Unable to parse option value ".5" as duration`. Use `d=0.5` instead.

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm!

Comment: Strange, for me this does not work. I'm trying to check 4 mono tracks and it always checks the first only